# How to setup the VPN tunnel through SMPP

Tags: centos, vpn, installation, ssh-tunnel

I am trying to install VPN tunnel through SMPP on my centos server and need help or some tutorial which shows how to do it.

Comment: I've heard about using SMPP through a VPN, but building up a VPN over SMS... I think you will have high latencies no?

Answer (score 2):

You want to implement a VPN over SMS - not the other way around?

If so, short of implementing the IP protocol over SMS I can't really see a good way to make this work.
If you want to try that method though You can use [RFC 1149](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1149.txt) and [RFC 2549](http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2549.txt) as a reference/guide to implementing the transport layer.

---

(Yeah - not possible in any reasonable way as far as I can tell.  Ignoring everyhing else, what Lucas said about latency would be a killer. your connections would be timing out constantly.)

Comment: Hah, HTTP over SMS/MMS: http://www.extremetech.com/computing/95457-how-to-surf-t-mobile-without-a-data-plan (lesson in perverse incentives, putting a cap on data, but allowing unlimited SMS)

Comment: @cjc I'm not sure how they implemented this, but I would imagine HTTP is much easier than a VPN link (HTTP is just text & presumably a sequence number to ensure it stays in order, you'd have to base64-encode the VPN traffic or similar binaries). Interesting bit of software though - I applaud the ingenuity!